# CSS: Separate hover animations from other class-relevant animations

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Context**: I'm manipulating a div's size on hover, as well as its position when clicked. I'm using the CSS transform property to accomplish these 2 things.

**Issue**: I want a different transition timing for this div for size and position changes (primarily for the returning transition). However, both manipulations involve the same CSS property.

**Question**: How do I isolate/separate transition timing?

[Sample code here][1]

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('shifted');
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  //i would like for the div to move back in 1 second when .shifted is removed
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.shifted {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some logic which checks if the div has the class and if it doesn't then it will remove the 'shifted' class after 1 sec.

You also need a pseudo of hover on the 'shifted' to keep the div from flicking back and forth.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<style>
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.shifted {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

div.shifted:hover{
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
</style>

<div></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('div').click(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('shifted')){
    $(this).addClass('shifted')
  }else{
    setTimeout(function(){$('div').removeClass('shifted')},1000)  
  }
})

})//doc ready

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have some javascript to assist with your CSS transitions.

Here's the JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gngLqzor/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.box.hovered {
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1.5);
}

.box.shifted {
  transform: translateX(50px) scale(1);
}

.box.shifted.hovered {
  transform: translateX(50px) scale(1.5);
}
```

**JS**

```
var boxShiftTimeout,
    box = document.querySelector('.box'),
    stateClasses = {
      hovered: 'hovered',
      shifted: 'shifted'
    };

box.addEventListener('click', onBoxClick);
box.addEventListener('mouseenter', onBoxMouseenter);
box.addEventListener('mouseleave', onBoxMouseleave);

function onBoxClick() {

  var el = this; 

  if (boxShiftTimeout) {
    return;
  }

  if (el.classList.contains(stateClasses.shifted)) {
    boxShiftTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
      el.classList.remove(stateClasses.hovered);
      el.classList.remove(stateClasses.shifted);
      boxShiftTimeout = null;
    }, 1000);
  }

  else {
    el.classList.remove(stateClasses.hovered);
    el.classList.add(stateClasses.shifted);
  }
}

function onBoxMouseenter() {
  this.classList.add(stateClasses.hovered);
}

function onBoxMouseleave() {
  this.classList.remove(stateClasses.hovered);
}
```

---

You will notice that I don't use CSS hover. This is because if you don't move the mouse right after the click, hover gets applied to the box even after it has been shifted. That's why the `hovered` class gets removed before applying the `shifted` class.